# Linux Kernel mutex_lock_interruptible

Tags: linux-kernel

The mutex_lock_interruptible() function in the linux kernel basically tries to lock a mutex and will continue waiting until a task is interrupted. Well how do I actually interrupt a task?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Suffix `_interruptible` in Linux kernel means that waiting by the function will be interrupted if thread(process) receives the *signal*.

It can be signal sent by `kill()` user-space function, or signals generated by specific functions when condition met, e.g. by the timer (`create_timer()` when time is expired, or by asinchronous IO when pending operation has been completed.

Note, that *uninterruptible* wait cannot be interrupted even by SIGKILL, that is process cannot be finished until such wait ends.

Comment: I have a kernel thread waiting for a mutex and I want it to stop waiting and return an error code, how can I do that? Is send_sig() the way to do it or is there a better way?

Comment: Yes, you may use `send_sig()` for send signal within the kernel.